# How can we include geometry node in particules option of blender?

Tags: modeling

For example we create a strawberry with yellow dots and with the particle we put the strawberries on the cakes but the yellow dots disappeared why ? And how to fix it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't have a particle system _of_ a particle system unfortunately, If you want both, you will have to apply  one of the geometry node modifiers. For example - apply the "dots" to the strawberries (apply the modifier), then instance the strawberries.

Comment: Thanks Christopher I will try that.